# Is there a way to load swiftUI view into NSView?

Tags: swiftui, nsview, appkit, rootview, contentview

I would like to know if it's possible to load a SwiftUI view into an NSView.
I was hoping to set the windows content view to aSwiftUI but it seems impossible
`window?.contentView = view` where view is of swiftUI

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we talk about `AppKit` which `NSView` is part of. There is a way to convert SwiftUI view to NSView using `NSHostingView` like this:

```swift
NSHostingView(rootView: yourSwiftUIView)
```

So, you can write:

```swift
window?.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: view)
```

If you need the same for `UIKit` - use `UIHostingController` in pretty much similar but slightly more complex way:

```swift
UIHostingController(rootView: view).view
```